# Number of jobs by a company listing

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I see a company X has more than 13 job listing in their company profile. But when the company name is given as the search term in the job search it returns only 11 results. So how are the jobs in the company search page different from the job search page. Are not all the jobs displayed in the job search page?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a company?

Comment: Can you search trivago..